Symmetric Subgroups of Symmetric Groups
I am interested in all of the ways that symmetric subgroups, $S_n$, can be found inside of a larger symmetric group $S_N$. Starting with $N=4$ we can look up the subgroup lattice for $S_4$ and throw away everything that isn't a symmetric group. Working up to conjugacy class we have:

On the bottom row $S_3$ fixes one position, whereas the $S_2$ subgroup fixes two positions. There is, however, also a second copy of $S_2$ within $S_4$ which swaps pairs of points.
We can move up to N=5 by looking at a list of $S_5$'s subgroups. We find a twisted copy of $S_3$ inside of $S_5$. This contains the pair-swapping $S_2$ from before yielding:

If we now move up to N=6 we find an exotic copy of $S_5$ inside of $S_6$. Hence, we get a second copy of all of the above structures. [Edit: My first guess was wrong here. I typed up some GAP code to find the right answer. Here it is.]

I now have some GAP code which can quickly produce these lattices for small values of $N$.
But before I go any further exploring these things myself I should ask: Is anything known about these lattices? As the structure grows does it ever become regular? I know that what happens at N=6 is exceptional. Is this problem any easier than mapping out all of the subgroups of $S_N$ (which I know is very difficult)?
Any thoughts would be much appreciated!
[Edit: After getting my code working, I thought I should share a bit more] For good measure, here is $S_7$. Note how it breaks the nice symmetry which $S_6$ had:

What is new here are the red $S_7$, $S_5$, $S_4$, and $S_3$ groups on the central row. They come along with some new connections which I have marked as dashed lines.
From here, things seem to just get more complicated. I have been able to figure out that the layer-by-layer widths of these lattices continue as follows. Its actually in the OEIS already as A378177.
$S_1$: 1
$S_2$: 1, 1
$S_3$: 1, 1, 1
$S_4$: 1, 2, 1, 1
$S_5$: 1, 2, 2, 1, 1
$S_6$: 1, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1
$S_7$: 1, 3, 5, 5, 3, 1, 1
$S_8$: 1, 4, 7, 10, 4, 2, 1, 1
$S_9$: 1, 4, 10, 13, 5, 2, 2, 1, 1
$S_{10}$: 1, 5, 12, 22, 9, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1
$S_{11}$: 1, 5, 15, 27, 11, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1
$S_{12}$: 1, 6, 20, 47, 17, 8, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1
$S_{13}$: 1, 6, 23, 56, 19, 9, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1
$S_{14}$: 1, 7, 28, 84, 25, 14, 6, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1
$S_{15}$: 1, 7, 34, 104, 31, 15, 7, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1
$S_{16}$: 1, 8, 39, 147, 40, 21, 9, 7, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1
$S_{17}$: 1, 8, 45, 175, 48, 22, 10, 7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1
As @verret noted, the second column is Floor(N/2). Note also that the 4th column seems to always be the maximum for each row. Finally note that all of the late rows seem to end with a double count-down ... 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1. This suggests that at least the tops of the lattices will become regular in the $N\to\infty$ limit.

In fact, in your $S_6$ lattice, you have $\textbf{too many}$ copies of $S_2$, there are only three conjugacy classes.

As for the general problem, I'm not sure. One should be able to work out the bottom of the lattice (for example, the number of $S_2$ is $\lfloor N/2\rfloor$) and the very top of the lattice is fairly well understood, but I'm not sure you could get a complete compact description in general...

@verret Thanks for the comment! I have drafted up some GAP code which can produce these lattices for small N. I'll keep playing around with this for a while on my own.

Check whether when you go up from S_5 you see a pattern for the placement of the symmetric groups for n>5 (my intuition could be wrong, but remember solving by radicals was possible up to 5, maybe there is a distorting pattern for greater numbers

@DanielGrimmer I encourage you to work out on your own what happens for $S_2$, $S_3$ perhaps even $S_4$ or $S_5$ inside general $S_n$, maybe you will get some intuition for the general case?

My predictions (from my deleted answer) don't match some of these table numbers. Rereading your question, I realize these numbers are from OEIS (via GAP), so I've posted a question wondering why I'm not getting the expected answers.

@coiso I'm glad you found that the numbers came from some GAP code. I'll be away from my computer for the next few days. Let me know if you find anything interesting.

"This suggests that at least the tops of the lattices will become regular in the "$N\to \infty$ limit." This is the content of the following MO post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302185/counting-symmetric-subgroups-of-symmetric-groups

There is precisely one line $S_m-S_n$ ($m>n$) in your Hasse diagram for every multiset $\{[H_1],\cdots,[H_k]\}$ of conjugacy classes of degree $n$ permutation groups  with total index
$$ \sum_{i=1}^k [S_n:H_i]=m. $$
(from using orbit-stabilizer to classify $S_n$-sets of size $m$), with two caveats:

For $S_n\to S_N$ to be an embedding, i.e. the action faithful, the kernel must be trivial. The kernel is the intersection of the normal cores of the stabilizers $H_i$. The only normal subgroups of $S_n$ are $1,A_n,S_n$ and $V_4\triangleleft S_4$, so we need at least one subgroup which is not these.
Inequivalent actions $S_n\to S_N$ have distinct images, except when related by an outer automorphsim of $S_n$. The only outer automorphism comes from $\mathrm{Out}(S_6)\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$. (Also see.)

This means to classify the copies of $S_n$ in $S_N$, we don't need to find all subgroups of $S_N$ of order $n!$, we need to find all subgroups of $S_n$ of index $\le N$.

To count the number of $S_3$s in $S_N$ for example, observe the subgroups (up to conjugacy) are $[C_1],[C_2],[C_3],[S_3]$ with indices $6,3,2,1$. To be faithful, we need at least one $[C_1]$ or $[C_2]$. Thus, the copies of $S_3$ are in bijection with the solutions $(a,b,c,d)$ to the Diophantine system
$$ \begin{cases} 6a+3b+2c+d=N \\ a+b\ge1 \end{cases} $$
You can solve this with generating functions explicitly, but it isn't pretty.
For $S_2$ the system is $2a+b=N,a\ge1$ which has $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ solutions.

What about the pattern in the second half of all the rows? The smallest-index subgroups of $S_n$ are $S_n,A_n,S_{n-1},A_{n-1},S_{n-2}\times S_2,\cdots$ (see here), so when $n>N/2$ we need only consider $[S_n]$s and $[A_n]$s with one $[S_{n-1}]$. This leads to solving $2a+b=N-n$ which has $\lfloor\frac{N-n}{2}\rfloor+1$ solutions.
When $N=2n$ or $2n+1$ we get two more cases, $\{[S_{n-1}],[S_{n-1}],[S_n]\}$ and $\{[A_{n-1}],[S_n]\}$, so it's always $2$ more than what you would get by extending the pattern from the last half.

Thanks so much for this answer! And your related MO question. If I understand correctly, the copies of $S_3$ inside $S_N$ will be in one-to-one correspondence with the solutions to that Diophantine system. And likewise the copies of $S_4$ will correspond to the solutions of some other Diophantine system. Is there any way to tell which $S_3$s are contained in which $S_4$s by this Diophantine analysis? I.e., will some of the $S_3$ solutions be "contained in" some of the $S_4$ solutions?
